# Создание отчетов в формате docx Java

Tags: java, docx

Подскажите хорошую и простую библиотеку для создания отчетов в формате docx.
Задача очень простая - требуется создавать документы с тестовой частью и таблицами, ни каких рисунков, графиков и т.п., единственное требование, чтобы все было красиво

Пробовал jasper report, pdf файлы и др. он отлично создает, а вот docx как то коряво получается, все куда-то плывет, может если основательней разобраться, то все получится, но чет-то не хочется тратить кучу времени на такую библиотеку.

Есть еще docx4j, он хорошо подходит, если надо заполнить готовый шаблон. А вот чтобы что-то изменять в шаблоне очень мало информации и примеров его использования.

Может есть какая-то библиотека не требующая много времени на изучение или хотя бы с хорошими примерами ее использования. Или хотя бы какой из них стоит изучать основательно.

Answer (score 2):

Могу смело рекомендовать библиотеку Apache POI.
Документация полная, примеров работы в интернете крайне много.